# How to sync commits of a new local branch originated from a previous commit to remote repository?

Tags: git, version-control

On my local repo, I have created a new branch from a previous commit using SHA of that commit. Steps followed:

```
git checkout <sha of some previous commit>
git branch new_branch
```

After that, I made changes on `new_branch` and committed my work.

Now, I want to push this newly created branch to my remote repository (Bitbucket). For that,  I made a new branch on bitbucket with the same name `new_branch`.

And after that, I tried to push changes of my local `new_branch` to using:

```
git push -u origin new_branch
```

But there is following error:

```
>  ! [rejected]        new_branch -> new_branch (non-fast-forward) 
> error: failed to push some refs to
> '<url to my repo>' hint:
> Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
> hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g. hint:
> 'git pull ...') before pushing again. hint: See the 'Note about
> fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

There is an error because both branches had originated from different commits. I understand it was an incorrect way to create that `new_branch` on remote repository (bitbucket).

How can we create a new branch in the remote repository (bitbucket) which is in sync with the local branch which was created from a previous commit?

Thanks.

**Solution**:

1. I deleted branch namely `new_branch` from Bitbucket.
2. `git push origin HEAD`

Note: `git push origin new_branch` gave the following error:

> error: src refspec new_branch does not match any.

Comment: "*For that, I made a new branch on bitbucket with the same name new_branch*", namely, how ?

Comment: @ Piotr Skotnick, Using bitbucket's online interface

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> > ! [rejected] new_branch -> new_branch (non-fast-forward)
> >     error: failed to push some refs to

You don't need to create a branch in GitHub. Just push your local branch (a new branch will be created automatically if not exist).

Create another branch from here and push to remote.

```
$ git checkout -b new_branch2
$ git push origin HEAD         # push local new_branch2 = HEAD to remote
```

Answer (score 0):

```
>  ! [rejected]        new_branch -> new_branch (non-fast-forward) 
> error: failed to push some refs to
```

If this is really the output, then for your local branch `new_branch` a remote branch `new_branch` already exists and they are incompatible.

Based on how you created your local branch, I’m not actually sure you ever went onto that branch. Checking out a commit hash will put you on a detached HEAD. You then created a branch on that commit, but you never switched to it. So your original steps should have a `git checkout new_branch` after them before commiting. (Note that you can create a new branch pointing to a commit hash using just `git checkout -b new_branch <commit-hash>`)

> For that, I made a new branch on bitbucket with the same name `new_branch`.

How exactly did you do that? After all, branches are created by *pushing* something to them. So it’s likely that you pushed something else to it in order to create the branch—which would explain why your actual local branch is not compatible with the remote branch.

I’d suggest you to use `git fetch` to get the full state of the remote into your local branch and then look at the full history and all branches (for example using `gitk --all`). That way you can understand what exactly is going on and where the branches are pointing to.

If you end up figuring out, that the remote `new_branch` is just a copy of the `master` (for example), then you can just force push your local `new_branch` to it to replace the remote state. Otherwise, you might want to create *another* local branch to fix up all the stuff by merging the changes properly.

Answer (score 0):

As you understand that create `new_branch` on bitbucket is incorrect since the `new_branch` is checked out from the latest commit sha not the one you specified.

To sync with remote, you should push local `new_branch` directly to bitbucket. So you should follow this way:

1. Delete the branch you created on bitbucket
2. `git push -u origin new_branch`

This will automatically create `new_branch` on bitbucket and set the tracking relationship between local `new_branch` and remote `new_branch`.

Comment: There was the following error while using the command on step2: [error: src refspec new_branch does not match any.]. 
git push origin HEAD,  worked like a charm